# How do I set up my npm directory and bash folder, so I can eventually npm init @vitejs/app?

Tags: three.js, npm-install

C:\Users\ChristianMiller>npm list -g -depth-0
ChristianMiller@1.0.0 C:\Users\ChristianMiller
`-- make-dir@3.1.0` -- semver@6.3.0

Right now I'm stuck setting up my directory,  does anyone have tips then can share to get me going, I'm eventually aiming to build a 3D website portfolio with vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

if you visit `vitejs` documentation site, section `Get Started`, and follow the instructions, you should find what you need to setup your project and run it in a minute.

- Step 1:

`cd C:\Users\ChristianMiller`

- Step 2: Initialize your ViteJS app folder

`npm init @vitejs/app my-vue-app`

It will ask you which framework you want to use, select `vanilla` here.

- Step 3: Install all the required dependencies from `package.json`

```
cd my-vue-app
npm install
```

- Step 4: Add `threeJS` to the project

`npm install --save three`

- Step 5: run the project preview

`npm run dev`

Everything should be ready here to start your new project with ViteJS and ThreeJS.
Visit `http://localhost:3000` to see the preview.